# ionic2 push get token

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic2

Is there a way to get the token outside the register method later in the code?
I mean, is the token assigned to an attribute of the Push object somewhere?

```
  push.on('registration', (data) => {
    // console.log("device token ->", data.registrationId);
    //TODO - send device token to server
  });
```

The above code works to see the token, yet it is outside of my controllers or providers. I have to access it later in my code. I want to send the token to server, but for this I first have to get the user name. Since push registration happens somewhen when `device ready`, I yet do not have access to the user name. Another problem is for new users where token can not be assigned to a specific user yet and `send device token to server` can not be executed.

Comment: Hi El Dude. If my answer has helped you to solve your problem please mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **localStorage**.

**setItem**

```
localStorage.setItem('device_token', data.registrationId);
```

and use it like this

**getItem**

```
 this.device_token = localStorage.getItem('device_token');
```

Comment: From my understanding using iOS for development the token is set when the user confirms to allow push messages and remains constant then. One should be able to read it anytime from the Push library, no?

Comment: @ElDude  Yes. Token remains the same as long as the user does not install the application again. Then he gets another token.